# Recording both headset input and internal mic input at the same time

Tags: macos, cocoa, audio, core-audio

On a newer Mac, it appears that OS X treats the 'microphone' as a special device. When no headset is attached, it uses the "internal mic". When I add a headset it transparently switches over to the headset mic (in this case from an iPhone headset).

Is there any way (low-level code perhaps?) I can have it record from the internal mic AND the headphone mic concurrently? I have an application where this is essential.

I could probably use a USB mic instead of the headset, then they would be two separate devices - but I'd like to support headset style devices (or any line-in input) as well.

Comment: It's not even sure it is possible at the hardware level.  If I were them, I would have put just one DAC for the input on the integrated sound board (with a pre-amp on the path coming from the headset).  However, this is just a stupid guess of mine.  I know for sure that you can output simultaneously two different sounds on the speaker and the line out. So they certainly have two DACs on the output.

Comment: Yeah I think you're right. Which unfortunately kills my project :(  If you'd like you could word your reply as an answer and I can mark it accepted.